# SQL query, multyplying in select with Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL database.

```
Company_Shares

HolderOfShares    NumberOfShares    ShareOfComapy 
A                 100               Nova
A                 30                Samsung
B                 40                Nova
C                 70                Hyper
A                 +20               Samsung
B                 +50               Nova   


Price_of_single_Share

ShareOfComapny    PricePerShare
Nova              10
Samsung           17
Hyper             13
```

Via this two tables I need to create a query which sums up the NumberOfShares for each HolderOfShares and multyply the number of shares with its price and order it by the totaly cost of shares. Final example should looks like that:

```
HolderOfShares    TotalCostOfItsShares
A                 1850
C                 910
B                 900
```

Could anybody help me with this query please.

Comment: This is a pretty basic join/group by query.  Are you familiar with SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is going to be answered, the answer might as well be correct:

```
SELECT cs.HolderOfShares,
       SUM(cs.NumberOfShares * poss.PricePerShare) as TotalCostOfItsShares
FROM Company_Shares cs JOIN
     Price_of_single_Share poss
     ON cs.ShareOfCompany = poss.ShareOfCompany
GROUP BY cs.HolderOfShares
ORDER BY TotalCostOfItsShares DESC;
```

Note:  I assume that `ShareOfComapy` is a misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

join those two tables

```
    SELECT a.HolderOfShares, SUM(a.NumberOfShares) * b.PricePerShare as TotalCostOfItsShares FROM Company_Shares as a
    JOIN Price_of_single_Share as b ON b.ShareOfComapy = a.ShareOfComapy
    GROUP BY a.HolderOfShares
```